# Cohomology of pushforward of a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and $C$ be a smooth curve on $X$ ( let $j$ denote the embedding of $C$ inside $X$). Let $L$ be a line bundle on $C$. Assume that it's known that $h^0( j_*(L) \otimes \mathcal O_X(-1))=0$, then can we say that $h^0( j_*(L) \otimes \mathcal O_X(-n))=0$ for all positive integer $n$?

Can we say that $j_*(L) \otimes \mathcal O_X(-n) \hookrightarrow j_*(L) \otimes \mathcal O_X(-1)$? This is true if  $j_*(L)$  is a bundle. Does it also  hold in other situations?

**Edit (from OP's comment):** Can we argue like this:  One can note that, $H^0(X, j_*(L) \otimes \mathcal O_X(-m)) \cong H^0(C, L \otimes j^*(\mathcal O_X(-m))$  for any $m$ using Projection formula.

From the exactness of Pullback functor, one has $\mathcal O_X(-n) \hookrightarrow \mathcal O_X(-1)$ on $X$ induces  $j^*(\mathcal O_X(-n) )\hookrightarrow j^*(\mathcal O_X(-1))$ on $C$. Tensoring this with the line bundle $L$ and taking cohomolgy one has $$h^0(L \otimes  j^*(\mathcal O_X(-n) ) \leq h^0(L \otimes j^*(\mathcal O_X(-1) ) =0$$ and hence we have the desired result. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: How about using the projection formula, then?

Comment: @yearning4pi, Can we argue like this :  One can note that, $H^0(X, j_*(L) \otimes \mathcal O_X(-m)) \cong H^0(C, L \otimes j^*(\mathcal O_X(-m))$  for any $m$ using Projection formula. From the exactness of Pullback functor, one has $\mathcal O_X(-n) \hookrightarrow \mathcal O_X(-1)$ on $X$ induces  $j^*(\mathcal O_X(-n) )\hookrightarrow j^*(\mathcal O_X(-1))$ on $C$. Tensoring this with the line bundle $L$ and taking cohomolgy one has $h^0(L \otimes  j^*(\mathcal O_X(-n) ) \leq h^0(L \otimes j^*(\mathcal O_X(-1) ) =0$. and hence we have the desired result. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: Pullbacks are generally not left-exact. It may be better to observe that $f^{\ast}(\mathcal O_X(m))$ is $\mathcal O_C(m)$. In fact, one can twist an injection $\mathcal O_C\to\mathcal O_C(n-1)$ and then tensor with $L$ to get the desired injective morphism.

Comment: @yearning4pi, Oh, I see, pull back is an exact functor on short exact sequence of locally free sheaves. Isn't $\mathcal O_C(m)$ just a notation which stands for the line bundle given by the pullback $j^*(\mathcal O_X(m))$?

Comment: I would disagree re: notation, but it may not be completely relevant. The idea of my previous comment was simply to build your own injection $\mathcal O_C(-n)\to\mathcal O_C(-1)$ without using a given one on $X$.

Comment: @yearning4pi, Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @yearning4pi, Could you please briefly indicate how to geometrically understand the notation $\mathcal O_C(m)$ in contrast to the notation $\mathcal O_C(n_1.p_1+...n_k.p_k)$ for the points $p_1,..p_k \in C$ and in integers $n_1,...n_k \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: The latter is a Weil divisor $n_1p_1+\dots+n_kp_k$, which may be fairly geometrically suggestive. In fact, when I want to think about $\mathcal O_C(m)$ geometrically, I would view it as the intersection of $C$ with a degree $m$ hypersurface in $\mathbb P^N$ (for positive $m$).

Comment: @yearning4pi, just out of curiosity : if we know that $C$ already lies in a degree $m$ hypersurface in $\mathbb P^N$, will then  $\mathcal O_C(m)$ be a valid divisor on $C$ with the same interpretation?

Comment: Yes, a general hypersurface will intersect $C$ in codimension $1$. Consider, for instance a plane curve in $3$-space.

Comment: @yearning4pi, And if we know that $C$ already lies in degree $m$ general hypersurface say $X$ in $\mathbb P^N$, then $\mathcal O_C(m)$ on $C$ corresponds to a divisor on $C$ obtained as a intersection of $C$ with some other smooth(or general?) hypersurface of degree $m$ say $Y \neq X$ in $\mathbb P^N$?

Comment: Yes. I find it hard to elaborate beyond my previous comments. The ideas are essentially in Hartshorne AG section (II.7). In particular, the choice of $Y$ from your previous comment corresponds to a choice of section $s$ as in (II.7.7).